# How can I check whether a string of words exists in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery-ajax quiz that uses php to do the validation.
One of the questions asks for the three main characters of a story, but consider they could be entered
`char1 char2 char3`       `char2 char1 char3` etcetra.

How can i check whether the user string has char1, char2 and char3 within it, no matter what order they are in?

Comment: `preg_match('/\s*((char1|char2|char3)\s*){3}/i', $string);` instead of {3} you could also use + but that would allow for more than 3 answers and/or duplicates. Remove the __i__ (after `{3}/` to make it case sensitive.

Comment: so this `if (!preg_match('/\s*((char1|char2|char3) \s*){3}/', $_POST["string"]))
  {
  echo "1";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "0";
  }`

Comment: this doesn't work as I can type three random words and it accepts

Comment: Do the character names always appear as char1, char2, char3?

Comment: @Fred, no because the user could enter `char3 char1 char2`

Comment: @user2751288 if(preg_match() !== false)  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best with regex but you could do something like

```
  $string = "something char1 char2 char3";
if ((strpos($string,"char1") !== false) && (strpos($string,"char2") !== false) && (strpos($string,"char3") !== false) ) {
        echo 'found';
    }
```